# Firefox display overlapping div with strange behavior

Tags: html, css

I need to make 2 div with same color overlapping. On Chrome and IE9 it display fine. But on FF, there is a border bottom with strange color on the top `div` even if I don't set `border-bottom`. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/hHXkP/) is my jsfiddle. The issue occur at `title` div with "Some text here" text

Comment: Looks the same in FF as well as in chrome. Can u put a screenshot of how you want and what you are getting as well?

Comment: @NathanLee Thanks for your attention. But the problem has been solved by Libin. Have a nice day, Sir :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the box shadow you applied.

Adjust the values like this:

```
box-shadow: 9px -3px 10px -8px #000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change this box-shadow values to this:

`box-shadow: 9px -2px 10px -9px #000;`

This wont even make much difference in your shadow effects.

I think this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the box shadow on the .title, that is what is causing the line on FF.  You can reduce it to :

```
box-shadow: 9px 0 10px **-10px** #000000;
```

That gets rid of the line but of course looks slightly different.

Comment: I really sorry, I can't accept your answer because Libin answer closer to what I want. But I really appreciate your help. Thanks for your attention and have a nice day, Sir :D